# Cannot send value to paypal

Tags: paypal

PayPal IPN sends a notification to your script directly. Since the notification is coming from PayPal - NOT the customer that placed the order - My Login session doesn't exits this context .Therefore,all my login data doesn't exist in the session.I need my login session values to update my DB with paypal ipn value.How should i mentain my login session should i set browser session or other way can i send login primary key to paypal.

Comment: Your formatting makes it very hard to read ... you might want to reformat

Comment: You might also want to rephrase your question. I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Preetu: please update your post with a clear question that will help others guide you to finding the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending your costumer to PayPal you should perhaps save a temporary order(client info and items) into db with your own unique **order id**.

The **order id** you then send as **invoice** variable to Paypal which you later will receive from the IPN (callback).

From the IPN you get all the information you need on the transaction which you then also can check against your own temporary db.